# Find the value of $n$ when there's a constraint on $x$

Tags: probability, logarithms

> A computer is programmed to choose an integer between $1$ and $99,$ inclusive,
> so that the probability that it selects the integer $x$ is equal to $\displaystyle\log_{100}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right).$ Suppose that the probability that $81 ≤ x ≤ 99$ is equal to $2$ times the probability
> that $x = n$ for some integer $n$. What is the value of $n?$

According to question$,$ $$\log_{100}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=2\log_{100}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$$$\implies\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2$$
$$\implies 81\le x=\frac{n^3}{2n^2+n}\le99$$
Since $n$ is an integer $\implies n=\{163,164,\cdots,198\}$

---

What is wrong with my approach $?$ Why I am not getting a unique answer$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In front of your first equation there is a $\sum_{x=81}^{99}$ missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
Let $X$ be the random variable with distribution $P(X=x)=\log_{100}(1+\frac1x)$. Then $P(81\le X\le99)=\sum_{x=81}^{99}P(X=x)$, and the question states $2P(X=n)=P(81\le X\le99)$, so the formula
$$\log_{100}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=2\log_{100}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
is not a correct interpretation of the question. Do you know what it should be?

Comment: Silly me ${}{}{}{}$